# Custom event property not found in GA4 funnel analysis

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to set up a funnel, where I want the first step to be a user click on some predefined elements.

I've set up some custom JS to send `click` events whenever the user clicks on a button on our web site, where I'm adding custom parameters to record the clicked element's classes. In debug mode I'm able to see this event getting triggered in production (see first screenshot).

I'm then setting up a funnel where I'm looking for one of these classes as a first – and currently single – step (see second screenshot). But no data is reported. I know there can be some delay before data is available in these reports, but I've now waited a week to be 100% sure, and there's still nothing.

I must be missing something bleeding obvious here, but I'm totally unable to figure out what. Anyone with more experience got any hints?

Any help much appreciated!

---

**Screenshot 1 – Debug mode**

[image: Screenshot 1 – Debug mode]

**Screenshot 2 – Funnel analysis**

[image: Screenshot 2 – Funnel analysis]

Comment: Did they fix funnels in GA4 so that the steps can be something other than pageviews?   I haven't tried GA4 yet, but that could be a reason to migrate to it.

Comment: Not sure if "fix" is the correct word as GA4 is quite a different beast. But everything is an event now, including pageviews, and are used for funnel analysis.